# Two firewalls sharing same model

Tags: api-platform.com

I have two distinct authentication method for my API endpoints. All endpoints using the /vendor prefix uses the JWT implementation while the rest is using OAuth. Now, I want to create an endpoint that would be shared/can be accessed using the two authentication methods. I tried extending the entity and declared a resource using the derived model, the endpoint is showing but when I tried to get the result it always returns empty.